# wait for user to stop typing ss-multiselect-dropdown search

Tags: angular, dropdown

I am using the `ss-multiselect-dropdown`.

The problem is that as soon as the user starts typing, it starts calling the API defined in **LazyLoading**.

I have been trying to modify this to wait for the user to **stop** typing before it hits the API, so that typing 'test' doesn't call the API **four** times.

I am able to do this with a normal input, but the problem here is that it doesn't expose the input.

Any idea is appreciated in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting a timer until the user stops typing for a while (here 1100 milliseconds):

```
timer: any;

getList(searchText) {
 if (searchText.length >= 3) {
  clearTimeout(this.timer);
  this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
  // call api here
  }, 1100);
} 
else {
  this.list= [];
 }
}
```